# How to parse JSON with nested arrays and pass specific properties to the view in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Here's what I have for getting the title from that API:

```
// Action Method 1 to list titles
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var path = path;
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    var data = http.GetAsync(path).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    JObject r = JObject.Parse(data);
    IList<JToken> results = r["items"].Children()["volumeInfo"]["title"].ToList();
    ViewBag.myBooks= results;

    return View();
}
```

How do I do the next part? Here's the closest I've gotten to:

```
// Action Method 2 to display properties

// Option 1 - bunch of foreach loops

var title = "myTitle" //temporary variable
foreach (var item in json["items"])
{
    foreach (var books in item["volumeInfo"]) 
    {
        if ((string)books["title"] == title) // Gives an error here saying "Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty"
        {
            Console.WriteLine(books);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I parse this JSON?

I was thinking once I have that, I can pass it to my model (class) using:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyBooksClass>(jsonObject);
```

Comment: Would it not be possible to create a skeleton .Net class from the JSON (Simplified JSON structure provided) with the properties you are interested in and then call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SkeletonClass>(data)` directly on the API response.

Comment: `public class Response{public List<VolumeInfo> Items {get;set;}} public class VolumeInfo { public string Title {get;set;} public List<string> Author {get;set;} ...and so on with the properties you need }` Finally you would say `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the following classes to deserialize into (some properties have been stripped off):

```
public class VolumeInfo
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> Authors { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }
    // any other properties you need, add here
}

public class Item
{
    public VolumeInfo VolumeInfo { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a `Book` class and project the result into the desired class using Linq:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Authors { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }
}


// deserialize into classes
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data); 
// project to List<Book>    
var myBooks = response.Items
                  .Select(d => new Book 
                  { 
                      Title = d.VolumeInfo.Title, 
                      Authors = string.Join(",", d.VolumeInfo.Authors), 
                      PublishedDate = d.VolumeInfo.PublishedDate 
                  })
                  .ToList();        

foreach (var book in myBooks)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Title: {book.Title}, Authors: {book.Authors}, Date: {book.PublishedDate}"); 
}
```

Tip: paste json into Visual Studio (Edit -> Paste Special -> paste JSON as classes) or use a tool like [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to automatically create classes.